# Deferred deeplinking: Where do I fetch the referrer parameter in the application

Tags: android, google-analytics, deep-linking

I am trying to implement Deferred deeplink in which after installing the app from google play, I want to navigate the user to specific page depending on the referrer param in my app google play URL.
I read the implementation from [here](http://blog.urx.com/urx-blog/2014/10/7/implementing-deferred-deep-linking) and [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns)
but the testing is not successful and am not able to get Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found in the logs.
It is possible that am missing something, please help if anyone implemented the same.
Second part is where do I get the callback after I install the app with this referrer URL, So that I can navigate the user to a specific page in the app after app installation.

Comment: Can you show us your current code?

Comment: along with the code, as requested by @Kevinrob, please also include any relevant log output and/or stack traces in the case of a runtime or compiler failure.